# grepl across multiple columns - wildcard not working

Tags: r, wildcard, grepl

I'm currently working with a dataset that has multiple similar columns: item1, item2, etc. through item8. Within a function I'm writing, I've created a specific search to use as the first argument in an ifelse function that searches for a phrase in any of these columns:

```
grepl(exact_name, item1) | grepl(exact_name, item2) | grepl(exact_name, item3) | grepl(exact_name, item4) | grepl(exact_name, item5) | grepl(exact_name, item6) | grepl(exact_name, item7) | grepl(exact_name, item8)
```

This works fine, but I'd like to be able to apply this function to dataframes with some unknown number of item columns (all dataframes used will have at least one item column, and if it does have only one, it will still be in the format item1 instead of just item). I've tried using the * wildcard as follows:

```
grepl(exact_name, item*)
```

but I get an error with having a parenthesis after item* and can't even run the section. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If `item\\d+` are objects in the global enviornment, we can use `mget` to get the objects in a `list`, then loop through the `list`, apply the `grepl`, and `Reduce` it to a single logical `vector`

```
Reduce(`|`,lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^item\\d+$")), grepl, pattern = exact_name))
```

---

If the `item\\d+` are columns in a dataset, use `filter_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   filter_at(vars(matches("^item\\d+$")), any_vars(str_detect(., exact_name)))
```

Also, if we are not doing a partial match, then `==` should work as well

```
df1 %>%
   filter_at(vars(matches("^item\\d+$")), any_vars(.== exact_name))
```

Comment: That gives me this error: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable.` How can I work around this?

Comment: @ClaraR.  It is not clear from the post about the structure of `item1`, `item2` etc.  Are these vectors or data.frames ?  Please show the `dput` of a smaller subset of 'item1'

Comment: @ClaraR.  I updated the post  Please check if that works

Comment: They are vectors in a dataframe. `dput(test_frame$item1[1:3]` returns `c("Benjamin Wells Robinson", "Benjamin Wells Robinson", "Martha Ann Walls Robinson")`

Comment: @ClaraR.  In that case, please try with the second set of code.  A reproducible example would have been nice with expected output for testing